# Orbeon 4.7 bug with xhtml:iframe in an xforms:dialog?

Tags: orbeon

We are in the process of moving to a more modern version of Orbeon. After a lot of trial and error on pages that do not load we found what the problem was. When you have an iframe in a dialog that does dynamic loading based on submission attributes the page doesn't load.

Example of such a dialog:

```
<xxforms:dialog id="show-valueset-dialog" appearance="full" level="modal" close="true" draggable="true" visible="false">
   <xhtml:table>
       <xhtml:tr>
           <xhtml:td>
               <xforms:group ref="instance('valueset-navigation')[string-length(@url)&gt;0]">
                   <xhtml:iframe frameborder="0" src="{@url}/RetrieveValueSet?ref={@ref}&amp;effectiveDate={@flexibility}&amp;prefix={@ident}&amp;language={instance('language')}&amp;inline=true" width="100%" height="400"/>
               </xforms:group>
           </xhtml:td>
       </xhtml:tr>
   </xhtml:table>
</xxforms:dialog>
```

Any other place in the html:body works just fine. Any fixed/static URL works just fine too. The addition I should make is that any page served from eXist-db (the underlying db) is transformed using a custom XSLT. The page and the XSLT did not change from Orbeon 3.9 to 4.7 though.

Hence what I find in the orbeon.log as of Orbeon 4.7:

```
2015-03-03 16:36:46,455 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  - 
2015-03-03 16:36:46,455 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  -     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2015-03-03 16:36:46,455 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  -     |An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
2015-03-03 16:36:46,455 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  -     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2015-03-03 16:36:46,455 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  -     |org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException: oxf:/config/art-decor-theme-main.xsl (executing XSLT transformation): null |
2015-03-03 16:36:46,455 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  -     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Can anyone enlighten me as what changed in Orbeon 4.7 that triggers this so I may circumvent it? I cannot do remove functionality that the iframe brings I'm afraid.

Comment: Is the snippet above before or after the XSLT transformation? Could you send a small, minimal example? The easier we can try this the more likely we are to be able to fix it.

Comment: The snippet is before transformation. The transformation basically carbon copies everything, but adds some header stuff so all forms come out reasonably lookalike. I've created the smallest page I could think of. Can't find how to send through SO, so sent it directly.